# Does Linux sshd support sftp RESUME

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

a short question; does Linux sshd support resume on file transfer via sftp?

I've seen other similar questions, but not any real answer.

Comment: There is no `linux sshd`. There is openssh, dropbear [and others](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers). Which do you mean?

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474990/how-to-resume-failed-interrupted-downloads-with-sftp) by typing `linx sftp resume` into my favourite search engine. There are plenty of other references too.

Answer (score 0):

> does Linux sshd support resume on file transfer via sftp?

Yes, providing your sshd is OpenSSH >= version 6.3.